# FQL requesting error

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

```
String fqlurl="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()";
```

Does anyone could tell me what's wrong with this url?

I have illegalArgumentException error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [URLEncode](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) the query.

So, your query becomes :

```
SELECT+name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+%3D+me%28%29
```

from

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = me()
```